# Body of a SwiftUI .sheet() is being evaluated after dismiss and not presenting

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-sheet

### Use Case

If you have a SwiftUI `ContentView()` that displays a `PausableView()` based on a [@State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) property `presentSheet` that is also used to present a [.sheet()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)), the body gets evaluated differently based on how the `presentSheet` property is used inside the ContentView's body.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack{
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                presentSheet.toggle()
            }
            PausableView(isPaused: presentSheet) // 1. passing the property as a normal variable
                                                 // evaluates the body and the sheet on dismiss
//           PausableView(isPaused: $presentSheet) // 2. passing the property as a @Binding
                                                   // doesn't evaluate the body when it changes on dismiss
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
            DismissingView(isPresented: $presentSheet)
        }
    }
}
```

1. If the property is sent to the `PausableView(isPaused: presentSheet)` as a normal property, the body of the ContentView and **the body of the sheet are being evaluated when the sheet is dismissed**
2. If the property is sent to the `PausableView(isPaused: $presentSheet)` as a [@Binding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding), the body of the ContentView and **the body of the sheet are NOT evaluated when the sheet is dismissed**

### Is this normal behavior?

Is the sheet's body supposed to be evaluated when the sheet is not presenting anymore after dismiss?

Also, using @Binding instead seems to change completely how the view body is evaluated. But sending it as a @Binding is not correct because the property should be read-only in the child view.

### Visual

1 - Body gets evaluated when using a normal property (see lines 27-28 and 53-54):

[image: Body-redrawn-without-Binding]

2 - Body is NOT evaluated when using a @Binding (see lines 27-28 and 53-54):

[image: Body-NOT-redrawn-with-Binding]

### Sample Project

A sample project created in Xcode 13 is available here: https://github.com/clns/SwiftUI-sheet-redraw-on-dismiss. I noticed the same behavior on iOS 14 and iOS 15.

The relevant code is in [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/clns/SwiftUI-sheet-redraw-on-dismiss/blob/main/SwiftUI-sheet-redraw-on-dismiss/ContentView.swift):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DismissingView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            print(Self._printChanges())
        } else {
            print("DismissingView: body draw")
        }
        return VStack {
            Button("Dismiss") { isPresented.toggle() }
            Text("Dismissing Sheet").padding()
        }.background(Color.white)
    }
}

struct PausableView: View {
    var isPaused: Bool
//    @Binding var isPaused: Bool
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Elapsed seconds: \(counter)")
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                counter += isPaused ? 0 : 1
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            print(Self._printChanges())
        } else {
            print("ContentView: body draw")
        }
        return VStack{
            Button("Show Sheet") { presentSheet.toggle() }
            Text("The ContentView's body along with the .sheet() is being redrawn immediately after dismiss, if the @State property `presentSheet` is used anywhere else in the view - e.g. passed to `PausableView(isPaused:presentSheet)`.\n\nBut if the property is passed as a @Binding to `PausableView(isPaused:$presentSheet)`, the ContentView's body is not redrawn.").padding()
            PausableView(isPaused: presentSheet)
//            PausableView(isPaused: $presentSheet)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
            DismissingView(isPresented: $presentSheet)
                .background(BackgroundClearView()) // to see what's happening under the sheet
        }
    }
}
```

Posted on Apple Developer Forums too: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691783

Answer (score 0):

Using @Binding nets correct behaviour.

Body being evaluated when using a normal property seems to be a bug, because structs are supposed to be immutable... unless you use property wrappers like @State/@Binding/etc.

> Also, using @Binding instead seems to change completely how the view
> body is evaluated. But sending it as a @Binding is not correct because
> the property should be read-only in the child view.
> Why do you think it's not correct? Using @Binding means that you read and modify the data you pass into your child view but your child view does not 'own' it.

/Xcode 12 user here